# Routing problems, CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, routes

This might be a very silly question because I'm new to PHP frameworks. But I have got the concept of MVC framework. But this routing thing is very confusing me.

I created a controller and view for dashboard and set it as default. Then I wanted to check if the user is logged in then send him to the login page if it's not.

So, what I did in the routes is this:

`$route['default_controller'] = 'dashboard/index';`

`$route['login'] = 'login';`

But even if I add a thousand more controllers and routes, it still goes to the default i.e the dashboard. This was supposed to work `http://localhost/codeigniter/login`. I'm very sure I haven't put a redirect-to-dashboard code in the login page.

Comment: `$route['login'] = 'login';` is redundant. What code is in `index()` method of `Login.php` file?

Comment: Just loading the views in the index of the login

Comment: It's hard to offer any help without insight of actual code. Check two links on my profile where you can check out how to ask.

Comment: Did you read [the CodeIgniter documentation about routing](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html)?  Did you follow [the CodeIgniter tutorial](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/tutorial/index.html) and do the examples?

Comment: Did you make sure your controllers only have first letter on filename and class upper case.

Answer (score 0):

at first it's important to understand to routing in codeigniter.

The key for understanding is $route['url/path'] = controller/method (or "public function")

So. In your case, you routing to Login controller and index method (or index function...this it interpretation of codeigniter )

If you want to check if is user logged or not, you may try to check for examle session variable inside of called functon. But it depends on your application. But I think that is not good idea to check it in routes.php

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

The default controller in routes, will be the controller that opens your index or first page.
If your first page is in controller "pages", then that is your default controller. Do not use it for your secure dashboard pages
Your first page should be the index method in the controller. It should look like this

```
$route['default_controller'] = "pages";
```

Where pages is your first page controller

Comment: actually, I wanted it to be like Facebook. No homepage, just the login page. But my question is that every URL and route only lead to the default route